# Automatically Downloading Files from an ASPX Website in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, download, web

This is my first time posting on stack overflow, and I look forward to getting more involved with the community. I need to download, rename, and save many Excel files from an ASPX website, but I cannot access these Excel files directly via a URL (i.e., the URL does not end with "excelfilename.csv"). What I can do is go to a URL which initiates the download of the file. An example of the URL is below.

https://www.websitename.com/something/ASPXthing.aspx?ReportName=ExcelFileName&Date=SomeDate&reportformat=csv

The inputs that I want to vary via loops are "ExcelFileName" and "SomeDate". I know one can fetch these files with urllib when the Excel files can be accessed directly via a URL, but how can I do it with a URL like this one?

Thanks in advance for helping out!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `requests` library, you can fetch the file and iterate over chunks to write to file

```
import requests

report_names = ["Filename1","Filename2"]
dates = ['2016-02-22','2016-02-23']  # as strings
for report_name in report_names:
    for date in dates:
        with open('%s_%s_fetched.csv' % (report_name.split('.')[0],date,), 'wb') as handle:
            response = requests.get('https://www.websitename.com/something/ASPXthing.aspx?ReportName=%s&Date=%s&reportformat=csv' % (report_name,date,), stream=True)

            if not response.ok:
                # Something went wrong

            for block in response.iter_content(1024):
                handle.write(block)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! All I needed to add in addition to this was a password and username which was quite easy using requests. I wasn't aware of requests before; it's fantastic. I'm going to read up and try to better understand why we are using 1024 as a block size. That's the only part I don't understand.

Comment: Yeah, it's an amazing library for sure; no need to stick to urllib. Glad I could help!

Comment: I use 1024 just out of habit, using it when doing tutorials in the past. The docs state that 'iter_content' is used to keep from storing too large of objects in memory.